# Sublime navigation

Tags: javascript, sublime-text, editor-navigation

I need to navigate to js method source that I'm calling in sublime (for java script file). I try 'Ctrl'+'click method name' and nothing happens (It works for almost all IDE (eclipse, sts, netbeans, idea...)). I believe SubLime tool should have same ability (if it does not possible I need special plugin).

Can someone suggest correspond sublime plugin or other default hot key combination please?

Comment: Try visual studio code https://code.visualstudio.com

Comment: Thank you, It looks exactly I need. If you'll add this recommendation to answer i'll confirm it.

Comment: Not able to add answers It is on hold

Comment: I checked your tool, its a product from microsoft. They do nothing for open source community. I do not use windows or microsoft office. I use linux, I believe linux have good tools without ms dependencies., so sorry. Sublime is better for me i think now

Comment: [Where does my tool question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you're looking for something called 'Goto Definition' which is bound to the *F12* key by default.

You can change it's key binding, for sure. But please understand that though Sublime is an exceptional text editor, it is only a text editor. If you want all of these features out of the box and easy to use, you might prefer an IDE. (IMHO).

Comment: F12 does not work for me in sublime.

Comment: You can try [https://gist.github.com/kendellfab/6135193](https://gist.github.com/kendellfab/6135193) to achieve the `Ctrl + Click` functionality.

Comment: Which IDE do you mean? I have asked already about IDE but nobody answered, seems nobody knows _lol_

Comment: You may try WebStorm. It's a great IDE for web-development.

Comment: I'm not sure. _WebStorm_ needs a lot of system resources, also it is under paid license. I do not want pay for license, but I can make sponsor help if i really like tool or plugin.

Comment: I have red in details git conversation, that you provided me. It seems helped me a little. I have added their configuration and appeared ability to navigate to method sources by 'Ctrl'+'Method name click'. This recommendation you put in comments. Please edit the answer, and i will mark it like helpful. Thanks a lot.